# Mail.app slow to include new messages

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, exchange

With Leopard I was able to link to the University's Exchange 2003 server with and IMAP connection and mail out directly vie the SMTP client. With Snow Leopard I attempted to update to a full Exchange service (Exchange 2007). Almost all has worked OK (ical, address, etc.) except that new mail posted to my email account, which is visible using a 'web' interface to Exchange remains invisible for some random number of hours. Those who are running the Exchange server have no interest in discussing the problem. 
Has anyone else had a similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me as well.  However, it only happens on my iMac which has Entourage 2008 installed.  It never happens on my MacBook which only has Mail.app.  Not sure if there is a connection

Answer (score 0):

This (or something quite similar) happens to me as well. In my experience, the "sync" mechanism employed by mail.app gets caught up. You can see it happen if you hit Command-0 to view activity. The app gets caught up in the process of retrieving information and then just hangs.

Restarting the program repeatedly seems to work... it gets the messages bit by bit. Not that that's a long-term solution.

I also used Entourage before the problem. My mailbox is fairly big (over 3GB) and that caused huge problems for Entourage (data file over 100GB), so I switched.